# Laravel 5: belongsToMany SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found:

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I want to make a relation between my tables with belongToMany.
These are my three tables, that I want to connect.

```
fairkatert_task
-id
-user_id
-name

fairkatert_milestone
-id
-name

fairkatert_task_assign_milestone
-id
-milestone_id
-task_id
```

I use the belongToMany Method from Eloquent.

```
public function getTasks()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        'App\Http\Models\Task',
        'fairkatert_task_assign_milestone',
        'milestone_id',
        'task_id'
    );
}
```

And i only get the following SQL Error Message:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'milestone_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `fairkatert_task` where `fairkatert_task`.`deleted_at` is null and (`milestone_id` is null))
```

But I think I've done everything right but,but can't my mistake.

Comment: Have you read the error message carefully? The answer is right there.

Comment: I did, but i do not unterstand why it's looking for milestone_id in the "fairkatert_task" table. The relationship is managed in "fairkatert_task_assign_milestone".

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Josef's comment, you are looking directly at the answer - which you have acknowledged.

However you're struggling to understand:

> I did, but i do not unterstand why it's looking for milestone_id in the "fairkatert_task" table.

Reading Laravels documentation on a `belongsToMany` relationship it states:

> In addition to customizing the name of the joining table, you may also customize the column names of the keys on the table by passing additional arguments to the belongsToMany method. The third argument is the foreign key name of the model on which you are defining the relationship, while the fourth argument is the foreign key name of the model that you are joining to:

`return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'user_roles', 'user_id', 'role_id');`

Your relationship is:

```
public function getTasks()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        'App\Http\Models\Task',
        'fairkatert_task_assign_milestone',
        'milestone_id',
        'task_id'
    );
}
```

> The third argument is the foreign key name of the model on which you are defining the relationship

This means your third argument, `milestone_id` is trying to be found by `fairkatert_task`.

Comment: `public function getTasks()
 {
  return $this->belongsToMany(
   'App\Http\Models\Task',
   'fairkatert_task_assign_milestone'
  );
 }`


The first argument is the model which I want to make the many-to-many relation and the second argument is the pivoit tabele but i still geht the same error. 
I want to make the join over the pivoit tabel that the task tabel connect on task_id and the milestone tabel connect to milestone_id

Answer (score 0):

Oh my god i found my problem ... 
I had in my controller still an old method, that i load

Comment: @Will came across this in a review queue - I disagree, it is a conclusion to a question - it should be fleshed out but shouldn't be deleted.

Comment: True; I agree. But it absolutely needs to be expanded.

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer or it will probably be deleted